# Python3 numpy.fft.fft() vs Python2 numpy.fft.fft()

Tags: python, numpy, fft

After running the following code on my MacBook Pro, I find that the python3 numpy.fft.fft is faster than python2:

```
import random
import time
# import matplotlib
import numpy as np 
from scipy.fftpack import fft
# import cv2

coordinate = np.ndarray((1920, 1080, 2))
print(coordinate.shape)

for i in range(1920):
    for j in range(1080):
      coordinate[i][j] = (random.randint(0, 1920), random.randint(0, 1080))

print(coordinate[0][0])
# test = ([2.+4.j, 3.+3.j, 4.+4.j, 5.+3.j, 4.+2.j, 3.+1.j, 2.+2.j, 1.+3.j])
start_time = time.time();
res = np.fft.fft(coordinate)
end_time = time.time();
print("spend time: ", (end_time - start_time));
```

the result is:

```
% python2 ./test.py
(1920, 1080, 2)
[ 1022.   435.]
('spend time: ', 0.06316184997558594)
% python3 ./test.py
(1920, 1080, 2)
[1143.  678.]
spend time:  0.18218493461608887
```

The pythons' numpy version are both 1.19.1

Python2: 2.7.16

Python3: 3.7.3

Why the python2 is faster than the python3?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your test a bit which I think changes the conclusion a bit. Here is the modified code:

```
import random
import time
# import matplotlib
import numpy as np 
from scipy.fftpack import fft
# import cv2

np.random.seed(1234)

first = np.random.randint(0, 1920, (1920, 1080))
second = np.random.randint(0, 1080, (1920, 1080))

coordinate = np.dstack((first, second))
print(coordinate.shape)

print(coordinate[0][0])

start_time = time.time();
for i in range(100):
  res = np.fft.fft(coordinate)
end_time = time.time();
print("spend time: ", (end_time - start_time)/100);
```

First of all I let the `ftt` function run in a loop for 100 iterations to give a better average. Second I used the same seed for all tests, therefore the resulting array `coordinate` is the same for all tests.

The third change doesn't affect the test, it's only a faster way to create the `coordinate` array.

I let the test run several times using python2 and python3 (not on my machine, but I used repl.it) and my conclusion is that there isn't really much of a difference. On my end, testing with python3 more often than not was faster than python2.

Comment: I run your code on my Mac but it still has the issue. I try your code and my code on Alibaba Cloud Computing, and the python3 does run faster than python2.I think it's maybe the problem of python numpy on mac and I plan to post an issue on python github page. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had post this question on GitHub as an issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17130